# create dynamic component with dynamic list of attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a component which serves as the parent to create other components in its body. It receives a list of the component names and attributes to be created in format json through its Component Bundle Design Resources.

The problem that I am having is finding a work around to make the attributes dynamic. That is, in one component I´m going to pass one attribute, in another 2 attributes in another I might pass none...and so on. The attribute names are unknown, as well as the number of attributes.

```
 $A.createComponent(
   childCmpName,
   {
       parameter1: firstValue,
       parameter2: secondValue,
       parameter3: thirdValue,
       "aura:id": "animationCard" + id,
       "recordId": recordId
   },
     function(newComponent, status, errorMessage){
```

Where I have parameter1, parameter2, parameter3 is where I´m not being able to place a varible, because in one component it might be 'name' in another might be 'address'. It seems that the attribute name cannot be a 'varibale' it has to be the name of the actual attribute in the rendering component.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pass the whole object as a parameter to that function instead of passing the parameters individually.

// function

```
createComponent: function(childCmpName, attributes) {

    $A.createComponent(
        childCmpName,
        attributes,
        function(newComponent, status, errorMessage){
            // do something
        }
    )
}
```

// calling function can simply pass from JSON object containing attributes

```
var attributes = {
    parameter1: firstValue,
    parameter2: secondValue,
    parameter3: thirdValue,
    "aura:id": "animationCard" + id,
    "recordId": recordId
}
createComponent('c:myComponent', attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you Rahul for the hint, I ended up creating a java script map and calling it inside the create component function.

```
  var i;
  var attributesToAdd = new Map();

  for (i = 0; i < myParameters.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(myParameters[i]) !== 'undefined'){
      attributesToAdd[myParameters[i].name] = myParameters[i].value;
   }
  }

 $A.createComponent(
            childCmpName,
            attributesToAdd,
            function(newComponent, status, errorMessage){...}
```

Comment: You are converting an object to a map which is not really required in JavaScript. simply pass `myParameters` directly to `$A.createComponent`

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement is that the dynamic component receives the attributes one of the time not as an object, I did make that implementation before but it wasn´t accepted. Thanks Rahul